# jquery help delay

Tags: jquery

im trying to add a delay between each of these animations.

tried it with

```
slicebox = $( '#sb-slider3' ).delay(2000).slicebox({
```

on the last one but not joy. Any ideas? still new to jQuery

---

### full code below

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    var Page = (function() {
        var $navArrows = $('#nav-arrows').hide(),
            $navDots = $('#nav-dots').hide(),
            $nav = $navDots.children('span'),
            $shadow = $('#shadow').hide(),
            slicebox = $('#sb-slider3').delay(2000).slicebox({
                onReady: function () {
                    $navArrows.show();
                    $navDots.show();
                    $shadow.show();
                },
                onBeforeChange: function(pos) {
                    $nav.removeClass('nav-dot-current');
                    $nav.eq(pos).addClass('nav-dot-current');
                }
            }),
            init = function() {
                initEvents();
            },
            initEvents = function() {
                // add navigation events
                $navArrows.children(':first').on('click', function() {
                    slicebox.next();
                    return false;
                });
                $navArrows.children(':last').on('click', function() {
                    slicebox.previous();
                    return false;
                });
                $nav.each(function(i) {
                    $(this).on('click', function(event) {
                        var $dot = $(this);
                        if (!slicebox.isActive()) {
                            $nav.removeClass('nav-dot-current');
                            $dot.addClass('nav-dot-current');
                        }
                        slicebox.jump(i + 1);
                        return false;
                    });
                });
            };
        return {
            init: init
        };
    })();
    Page.init();
});
</script>
```

this is then repeated with

```
slicebox = $( '#sb-slider3' ).delay(2000).slicebox( {
```

changed to

```
slicebox = $( '#sb-slider2' ).delay(1000).slicebox( {
```

and
    slicebox = $( '#sb-slider0' ).delay(3000).slicebox( {

any ideas?

Comment: It's unlikely that the plugin uses the animation queue so `.delay()` can't be used here. Go for good old `setTimeout()`.

Comment: `delay()` only works with animations in jQuery's FX queue, it does'nt work with your own custom functions (unless you somehow add them to the FX queue). Consider using a `setTimeout` instead.

Comment: where would i put the setTimeout()? sorry for noob question!

Answer (score 0):

`delay()` is only useful with animations, but you can use [queue()](http://api.jquery.com/queue/) to register your own function with the animation queue:

```
slicebox = $("#sb-slider3").delay(2000).queue(function() {
    $(this).slicebox({
        onReady: function() {
            $navArrows.show();
            $navDots.show();
            $shadow.show();
        },
        onBeforeChange: function(pos) {
            $nav.removeClass('nav-dot-current');
            $nav.eq(pos).addClass('nav-dot-current');
        }
    }).dequeue();
});
```

This may be more readable (and is more chainable) than [setTimeout()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/DOM/window.setTimeout).

Comment: thanks but any chance you can give a more detailed working example? as mentioned pretty new to this

Comment: @user, try replacing your assignment to `slicebox` with the code in my answer. I filled in the ellipsis to provide more context.

Comment: Hi this worked thanks but it no longer responds to the css now for some reason?

Comment: @user, this should not be related. Are you sure CSS is properly applied when you do not call `queue()`?

Comment: Hi Frederic, thanks again for your help. I fixed the CSS issue but the problem i have now is the div doesn't appear until after the delay time has expired. I need it to appear but not animate until after the delay. (hope that makes sense)

Comment: @user, without further information I can only guess, but try calling `show()` before `delay()`. If the result is not what you expect, please consider updating your question with more details about the exact effect you want to achieve.